# git pair commit not showing up in GitHub contributions graph

Tags: git, github

I have a github profile with username 'xxxx'. When I commit code with the email in my profile (xxxx@email.com) it shows up in my contributions graph.

But we follow XP (Extreme Programming) practice at work and we usually pair program and commit our code in the format 'pair+xxxx+yyyy@email.com'.

I understand GitHub contributions graph shows only commits from my email but I want to know if there are ways to make pair commits to show up in my contributions.

Pair programming is used widely these days and I'm pretty sure there should be a work around for this.

**Note:**

- my email - xxxx@email.com
- my pair's email - yyyy@email.com
- commit goes as - pair+xxxx+yyyy@email.com
- I have enabled the settings "show public and private contributions"

Comment: How about adding multiple email addresses to your github account?

Comment: `I'm pretty sure there should be a work around for this` -- I doubt it. This isn't really a very useful feature, even for XP pairs.

Answer (score 2):

A commit can have only one author/email. Probably you're using a script that sets the author/email based on the pair. But you cannot get your pair commit to show up in GitHub contributions because GitHub contributions count commits only by sole author in the handle.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub [now supports pair programming](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors/). They have adopted the convention of including lines beginning with "Co-authored-by:" at the end of the commit message.

I have a simple git plugin that makes this easier to manage here: https://github.com/cac04/git-pair

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21253869)

Comment: @gp_sflover Sorry, I've edited this answer to include the key information from that link. That said, this question is specifically about GitHub and that link is to GitHub's own documentation. If the linked page changes then this answer may become out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest taking advantage of Git's author email and committer email fields. GitHub will show both of these (although in its pretty graphs, I believe only the author is considered to have contributed).

Set the author email to `xxxx` and the committer email to `yyyy` (or vice versa).

If you want `pair+xxxx+yyyy@email.com` to actually work, you'll have to add that email to your github account; but then your pair can't do the same, as only a single account can be attached to each email.

Comment: Thanks @Filmzy. Turns out we don't have a way to add the commits to the contributions graph of both members of the pair.

Answer (score -1):

Git itself only allows a single author and committer per commit. So when you use your paired user and email address, that one is interpreted as the single author/comitter of the commit.

On the GitHub side, GitHub will just match email addresses to GitHub accounts according to the registered emails in an account’s profile. This mapping is a 1-to-1 mapping, so GitHub will not be able to split this up into multiple users.

If you wanted to make this appear “better”, you would have to have a dedicated GitHub user account for the pair, so the paired email would match up with that one.

Comment: Thanks @poke. So I guess XP pairs don't have a way to make their commits show up in the contributions graph.